# Option to disable Horizontal Scrolling missing in 15.10

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 15.10, synaptics, scrolling

After upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10, the option to disable Horizontal scrolling is missing. I looked at the dconf-editor, and the property `org-gnome-desktop-perifipherals-touchpad`, and it does not have the option to disable Horizontal scrolling, unlike the same property in Ubuntu 15.04 (which was `org-gnome-settings-daemon-peripherals-touchpad`).

I also installed the Unity tweak tool, and the scrolling settings have the horizontal scrolling option greyed out.

Is there a different way to disable horizontal scrolling on the touchpad in 15.10, or have the earlier options re-enabled?

Comment: I'd love to solve this as well. The horizontal scrolling is really annoying to me and it just appeared out of thin air with my 15.10 upgrade!

Comment: Did you get it fixed, the bug are still there in 16.04?